# 2 Player Grid Based Strategy Game Identification

Tags: identify-this-game

I came across a strategy game in my feed yesterday, but can't seem to find the name.

The game is 2 players and a grid of X by X. Small grid as it seemed like a quick game. It wasn't a board but a grid of separated square tiles. The pieces were flat, and each player started on opposite sides of the grid. On a player's turn, you could move one of your flat discs one square in any direction, even diagonal. If you left a square and that square was empty, it was removed from the grid entirely for the rest of the game. You could move your piece on top of your piece or an opponent's piece, and the piece below would be trapped, unable to move. There was a 3 stack limit to these pieces.

The goal of the game was to move your piece past the opponent's final row of tiles, opposite of where you started (since empty tiles get removed as you move off them).

Comment: Do you have any images of the game?

Comment: I have no images, but the design was pretty basic. White square tiles, flat black discs for 1 player, flat red discs for the other.

Comment: Sounds almost like Isolation, but not quite. I don't see anything that fits your description on BGG, but perhaps this list will help: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2960/map-reduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game is called [Passo](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/401177/passo).

W Eric Martin from BGG has recently [released a video](https://youtu.be/ApaZAd5abm0?si=EQhTE7vWgV44ogNO) in which he talks about the game, maybe you saw it there.